# Enable observeEvent to trigger a eventReactive event

Tags: r, shiny

I have this small example of what I'm trying to do:

I am generating a normal distribution of data `sims` which changes based on which button is pressed. The first 5 values are printed in the first output box. From this, we collect samples of data and calculate the mean of each sample - `samp_sims`. As the slider is moved, the sample size changes and so do the mean -visible in the second output box.

It is ok that the population values `sims` don't change when the slider moves.  However, if a user is then to click "optionA" after "optionB", the population `sims` numbers change - but the sample mean numbers (output 2 at the bottom) do not update - they are still from the previous option.  They don't update until the slider is moved again.   I would like them to also automatically update when the button is pressed.  I tried doing this using an `observeEvent()` action - putting the same code for my `eventReactive()` event inside, but this didn't work.

Is there a way to ensure that the `samp_sims` values update whenever the slider moves or a button is pressed?

[image]

````
---
title: "test"
author: "James"
date: "9/28/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}

radioButtons("go", h3(""),
             choices = list("optionA" = 10,
                            "optionB" = 20),
             inline = TRUE
             )


```      


```{r, echo=FALSE}

 sliderInput("sampsize", label = "Sample Size:",
              min = 5, max = 100, value = 10, step = 1)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
sims <- eventReactive(input$go, {
 rnorm(1000, mean = as.numeric(input$go), sd = 2.5)
})
```


```{r, echo = FALSE}
    samp_sims <- eventReactive(input$sampsize , {
     apply(replicate(100, sample(sims(), input$sampsize, T)),2,mean)
  })
```

```{r,echo=FALSE}
observeEvent(input$go, {
})
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPrint({ sims()[1:5]})
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPrint({ samp_sims()[1:5]})
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a `list()` of two events for `eventReactive`. In your case,

```
samp_sims <- eventReactive(list(input$sampsize,input$go) , {
  apply(replicate(100, sample(sims(), input$sampsize, T)),2,mean)
})
```

A working example is below

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("t1", "t1"),
      actionButton("t2", "t2")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("view")
    )
  )
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  view <- eventReactive(list(input$t1, input$t2),{
    t1 <- input$t1              
    t2 <- input$t2
    
    rnorm(1)
  })
  
  output$view <- renderPrint(view())
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```